# Detecting if a coordinate on the screen is an interact-able.

Tags: c++, c, windows, api

This is regarding the C/C++ language ->
Is there some kind of Windows API that checks if a given position on the screen is clickable? For example, the windows icon on the bottom left, the red X on the top right of a program, or maybe the "enter" button in a web browser's search engine.
This sounds a bit complex, but maybe through IPC there's a way to do something like this? Thanks!

EDIT: By clickable, i mean anything you can associate with / interact with.

Comment: Define "clickable".

Comment: Anything you can interact with, essentially.

Comment: You can retrieve a window from a certain point (`WindowFromPoint`), but there is no way to tell if that window has an _on-click_ handler.

Comment: After retrieving window handle using `WindowFromPoint` you can check its window class name using function `GetClassName`, for most default _interact-able_ dialog controls it will be BUTTON, COMBOBOX, EDIT, etc. See details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx#system

Comment: Every thing on a MS-Windows screen is a Window.  Every Window receives events sent to it (mouse clicks for example).  Some Windows choose to ignore some events.  So every Window get a click if the mouse is over it, some choose to do something some choose not too.

Comment: I wrote a map display program which renders map tiles, I can click anywhere on the map and drag it. There is no formal dialog control used for this. To detect that my program responds to a mouse button message in this way (before actually clicked), you would need to disassemble it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost anything on screen is clickable (except things that hit-test as `HTERROR`, `HTNOWHERE` and `HTTRANSPARENT`).

The sane approach is to use UI Automation/MSAA. Call `WindowFromPoint`,  `ChildWindowFromPoint` or `RealChildWindowFromPoint` to get a HWND and then call [`AccessibleObjectFromWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx) to get a [`IAccessible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318466(v=vs.85).aspx) interface and call `accDoDefaultAction`.

A less sane option is to use `WM_NCHITTEST` to figure out what the mouse is over and send some fake `WM_NCLBUTTON*` messages.

Comment: This gives me something to start with! Thank you!